# P-MOSFET drain to source voltage reverse polarity protection

Tags: pmos, maximum-ratings

I have a question regarding the maximum drain to source voltage of a P-MOSFET used in reverse polarity protection circuit.

What would the Vds be if I applied 60V to the drain of the P-MOSFET?

As the source is connected to the top of the load the voltage when the P-MOSFET is on would be 60V minus RDS on voltage drop, so VDS would be very low, is that correct? Would a MOSFET with a max VDS rating above a few volts would work in this instance?

I am just trying to gauge whether I understand VDS correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, you need a higher Vds rating than that. The transistor cannot break down if somebody connects the battery backwards — that's the whole point of the circuit in the first place.

If that happens, there will be -60 V on the drain and 0 V on the source, so the Vds rating must be at least that high, preferably with some margin.

Answer (score 1):

**Never ignore the body diode.**

Look at the symbol again. There's a diode between the drain and the source. It's an intrinsic body diode and is formed by the construction of the MOSFET.

Even if you don't connect the PMOS gate, if you apply the supply voltage properly, the body diode will be forward biased and the circuit can run (even for a short time, depending on the limits).

When you connect the positive terminal of the supply (60VDC in your case) to the GND and the negative terminal to TP136 (i.e. reverse polarity), D22 will be forward biased but the body diode will be reversed biased and will block the current flow. Thus the **body diode will see -60VDC** (60VDC at its cathode with respect to its anode). The maximum drain-to-source voltage you see in Absolute Maximum Ratings is the breakdown voltage of that intrinsic body diode.

So you need to take the reverse polarity into account while selecting the PMOS. The absolute value of VDS should be higher than the maximum input voltage (of course, with a safety margin e.g. 10%).